# Insert html to .docx

Tags: php, html, docx

I use [phpoffice/phpword](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) to work with document templating, the example can be found here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/old/Template.php.

The problem is I need to insert formatted text which is `html` code generated from wysiwyg editor. I can't do:

```
$document->setValue('Value1', '<span>Sun</span>');
```

Document generation will be error, I guess because the library can't parse html along with the OpenXML. What I need to do is, probably, convert the html first to OpenXML, I tried it but always get:

[image]

I don't know. Any idea or suggestion how to deal with this ? will be greatly apreciated. Thanks.

Comment: do you want to insert literal html, which is html for display only - e.g. you're writing a document ABOUT html and need to show code camples? Or are you trying insert actual html, using it for markup/formatting of the inserted text?

Comment: I need to insert formatted text.

Comment: you can't, then. wordml is an xml-based format. it's NOT html. you need to write xml which corresponds to microsoft's requirements.

Comment: You can either convert the html to OpenXML (as you suppose), or you can insert an "altChunk", then rely on an altChunk aware tool (eg Word) to convert the HTML to raw OpenXML.  Would the latter approach (using Word) work for you?

Comment: @JasonPlutext I will look into the `altChunk`, never heard before. it could be the solution. I wonder how to do it with `php`. Many thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312321/solved-phpoffice-phpword-loadtemplate-not-rendering-word-as-it-should ... i've implmented it with success

Answer (score 3):

You can add html to table cell, see example:

```
$templateProcessor=$PHPWord->loadTemplate('Template.docx');

$value = '<b>TEST</b>';
$wordTable = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Table();
$wordTable->addRow();
$cell = $wordTable->addCell();                                
 \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($cell,$value);
                
$templateProcessor->setComplexBlock('SomePlaceholder', $wordTable);
```

Comment: It does not work. use `My <strong>example string</strong> with html tag.` and check your solution. This will result you 3 lines of texts instead of one line string. Thank you.