# PhpOffice\PhpWord loadTemplate not rendering Word as it should

Tags: php, phpword

I have problem with rendering HTML tags when load template. I use HTMLtoOpenXML to render it, but in the end it is just plain code.
I use this:

```
$workDescription = $entity->getWorkDescription();
$workDescription = \HTMLtoOpenXML::getInstance()->fromHTML(str_replace("<br />","<br>", stripslashes($workDescription)));
$workDescription = $this->replaceSpecialChar($workDescription);

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$document = $phpWord->loadTemplate($templatePath);
$document->setValue('Description', $workDescription);
$document->saveAs($file);
```

And PhpWord load document, and set description from variable, but output is something like this in rendered document:

```
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val='OurStyle2'/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space='preserve'>
            Test of CK Editor tags to transform them to word,
        </w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val='OurStyle2'/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space='preserve'>
            With a paragraph
        </w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

If I do not use HTMLtoOpenXML I get:

```
<p>Test of CK Editor tags to transform them to word,</p>
<p>With a paragraph</p>
```

So this looks like I'm missing something. Any help?

Comment: This is not possible to be done. Documentation say this:
t is not possible to add new PHPWord elements to a loaded template file.

I managed to solve this by commenting out line:
$replace = htmlspecialchars($replace);
In method setValueForPart of Template class.

Comment: any luck on doing it? i need exactly the same thing