# Convert HTML code to doc using PHP and PHPWord

Tags: php, html, openxml, phpword

I am using PHPWord to load a docx template and replace tags like `{test}`. This is working perfectly fine.

But I want to replace a value with html code. Directly replacing it into the template is not possible. There is now way to do this using PHPWord, as far as I know.

I looked at htmltodocx. But it seams it will not work either, is it posible to transform a peace of code like `<p>Test<b>test</b><br>test</p>` to a working doc markup? I only need the basic code, no styleing. but Linebreaks have to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the link to the github. It is working fine [Html-Docx-js](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js).

And it is the demo also available [here](http://evidenceprime.github.io/html-docx-js/test/sample.html).

Other option is this [Link](https://h2openxml.codeplex.com/).

```
 $toOpenXML = HTMLtoOpenXML::getInstance()->fromHTML("<p>te<b>s</b>t</p>");
    $templateProcessor->setValue('test', $toOpenXML);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works well, however, I only want the code of my tiny mc value.

Comment: What do you mean by that ? If you are using any code with free licence you just have to follow the T&C of that licence.

Comment: lets say I have the string "<b>test</b>". i want this to be transformed to a doc element, not a document. I will then place this element inside my docx using PHPWord. Placing existing doc elements works, but converting the html to them doesn't.

Comment: not clear what where you asking but have tried the link that I gave above ?? here is another link am adding where you can test a working demo of html to doc conversion with same source code.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but I do not want to have a downloadable file but code like bla<w:BR>bla

Comment: you just have to explore the code and then you can get that code too

Comment: I thought the tool generates a full document, I have not found a way of getting only the elements in it I need.

Comment: I think i should go the altchunks way

Comment: docx is similar to zip file if you rename the extension then you will find a document.xml in it you want the contents of that xml ?

Comment: Yes, I know, I was looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312321/solved-phpoffice-phpword-loadtemplate-not-rendering-word-as-it-should I will try HTMLtoOpenXML

Comment: getting error - `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "HTMLtoOpenXML" not found`

Answer (score 3):

The other answers propose [H2OXML](https://h2openxml.codeplex.com/) which only supports

- Bold, italic and underlined text
- Bulled lists

As described in their docs and their last update was in 2012.

I did some research and found a pretty nice solution:

```
$var = 'Some text';
$xml = "<w:p><w:r><w:rPr><w:strike/></w:rPr><w:t>". $var."</w:t></w:r></w:p>";

$templateProcessor->setValue('param_1', $xml);
```

The above example, shows how would be a striked text. Instead of "w:strike" you can use "w:i" for italic or "w:b" bold, and so on. Not sure if it works on all tags or not.

Comment: your shared link is broken, kindly update it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answer, Varun.

The simple PHP library H2OXML works for me https://h2openxml.codeplex.com/

```
$toOpenXML = HTMLtoOpenXML::getInstance()->fromHTML("<p>te<b>s</b>t</p>");
$templateProcessor->setValue('test', $toOpenXML);
```

I can now convert html code to insert it using PHPWord.

Comment: your shared link is broken, kindly update it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

$content = `'<p>Test<b>test</b><br>test</p>'`;

use it before IOFactory::createWriter();

```
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $content);
```